# Attach root-user screen session as non-root user

Tags: permissions, users, root, gnu-screen

I have a screen session that is started by root and I would like the non-root account (guest) be able to attach the root user's screen session in multi-user mode with `screen -x`. Is this possible?

When I have a detached screen session running as the root user and I try to login as the guest user and run `screen -x`, it tells me "There is no screen to be attached." I know the screen sessions are specific to different users but I would love to make root and guest share the same session. Would the guest user have to have root permissions to access the root user's screen sessions?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Should the "guest user" be able to use root permissions? Or just a view only screen?

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/219851/how-to-access-screen-created-by-other-users

Comment: @Lenniey Yeah they're gonna need root perms.

Comment: So, according to https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/219851/how-to-access-screen-created-by-other-users I need to start it with multiuser on. How would I go about doing that? It doesn't look like there are any flags to do this.